# Iterate over a random permutation of numbers in the range 0..n with large n

Tags: algorithm, random, numbers, permutation

I need to iterate over a random permutation of integers in the range `0..n`.

My first idea was to create an array of sequential integers and shuffle it. It works well for small `n` but gets slow and uses too much memory with larger `n`s (`n` > 1000000). (see: https://jsfiddle.net/cveqm4nj/ which takes >100ms to run on my machine)

How can I create an iterator which returns non-repeating integers in the range `0..n` without allocating an array of size n?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238201/discussion-on-question-by-simon-farshid-iterate-over-a-random-permutation-of-num).

Answer (score 0):

Shuffling is really easy, very fast and uses no extra memory at all if [done right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). (You still need the memory of the input array, though.)

```js
function shuffle_inplace(array) {
   let i = array.length;
   while (i > 0) {
      let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
      --i;
      [ array[i], array[j] ] = [ array[j], array[i] ];
   }
}
```

The shuffling:

- This uses O(N) time.
- This uses O(1) memory.

Including building the array:

- This uses O(N) time.
- This uses O(N) memory.

This could be turned into an iterator so you can return a single value each time it's called.

```js
function make_destructive_shuffle_iter(array) {
   let i = array.length;
   return function() {
      if (i == 0)
         return null;

      let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
      --i;
      [ array[i], array[j] ] = [ array[j], array[i] ];
      return array.pop();
   };
}
```

But that would still require O(N) memory. O(N) memory is required to keep track of which inputs you've already used/returned. But that memory doesn't need to be RAM. You could use the disk instead.